# HttpPostedFileBase null on controller / ajax resquest

Tags: ajax, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to upload a file and send it to controller, but it's always returning null. Here's the code:

```
  [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult Edita(string nome, string login, string email, string dataNascimento, HttpPostedFileBase avatar)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                       ......
            }
        }
```

Here's the javascript code.... am i missing anything? I've tried with formData as well, but couldn't make it work

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSalvar").click(() => {
            if (form.valid()) {
                var url = "@Url.Action("Edita", "Usuario")";
                let myFormData = $("#formUsuario").serializeArray();

                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: myFormData,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        autoUpload: true,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status == "OK") {
                                $("#userModal").modal("hide");
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution for this issue. My had the @Html.AntiForgeryToken() validation, so i removed it and it worked!